# back button issue after user login

Tags: grails, war

I have a user login page,after user inputs user name and password user redirected to home page.I am getting problem when  user clicks on back button after login  and he navigate to login screen,while he is all ready loggedin and have valid session.
I was try using clear cache by following code in my login page header-

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

please help me,where my code is wrong or i am missing something else.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a check for user-login in your login page. And if the user is already logged-in, just redirect him to the home page.